# Dynamically add string value in color property

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering how the following situation can be done?

I have the following code:

```
List<String> arrColorList = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: arrColorList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return new GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 42.0,
                                      height: 42.0,
                                      child: const DecoratedBox(
                                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          color: const Color.fromRGBO(66, 165, 245, 1.0)
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
        );
  }
```

What I want to achieve is to dynamically put the values of the `arrColorList` to the color property like this:

```
Colors.arrColorList[index] // Should end up in Colors.blue or Colors.red
```

But that is not valid. Any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter 'arrColorList' isn't defined for the type 'Colors'.

Change color list type string to Color

```
List<Color> arrColorList = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.yellow];
```

Complete source code

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: arrColorList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return new GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 42.0,
                                height: 42.0,
                                child:  DecoratedBox(
                                  decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                                      color: arrColorList[index]),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ))
```

Comment: Nice that is what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome. Happy coding with flutter

Answer (score 1):

It's good to create a List of Color "List"
and fill it with what colors you want.

In your case you can do this:

```
  List<Color> arrColorList = [
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.red,
    Colors.yellow,
  ];
```

and then use it like this:

```
  arrColorList[index]
```